# how to change the UI of opentok chat screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

I have integrated TokBox in my app.

I have implemented chat functionality using TokBox.

Below is the demo code for Tokbox chat.

Now I want to change user interface in that.

https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-ui

So how can I customize chat screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They have a new one: https://github.com/opentok/textchat-acc-pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so many research i got a solution  just add **OTKTextChatBundle** & **OTKTextChatLibrary**.now see all xib and change your UI.

**Note :** Don't add  OTKTextChatLibrary.bundle

see following screenshot for better understand

[image]